# How to update a given range in an array after multiple queries?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Suppose we have an array of length 10 like `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`. After multiple queries of range, I wanted to update this array in this manner:

```
update(2,5)  [1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1]

update (3,4) [1,2,3,3,2,1,1,1,1,1]

update (1,3) [2,3,4,3,2,1,1,1,1,1]

update(5,6)  [2,3,4,3,3,2,1,1,1,1]
```

and so on.

In short the update function will increase the values within the given range by 1.

It's not necessary to print the array after each update. I want to get the array after Q queries. So is there any efficient way to do this?
I already did the naive approach which took O(n^2) time.

Comment: Since the index starts from 0, shouldn't it be `update(1, 4)` and so on?

Comment: Your last array is `[2,3,4,3,3,2,1,1,1,1]`, so the most efficient approach would be to ignore the queries and simply output `[2,3,4,3,3,2,1,1,1,1]`. Can't beat O(1) time. *For a more useful solution, you should describe in words what you are trying to do, rather than letting us infer what we want from your example.*

Comment: To be precise query can ask an update from left most index to right most index

Comment: This sounds like a job for a segment tree or a Fenwick tree. Here are some lecture notes about them https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15451-f18/lectures/lec20-powerful-arrays.pdf

Comment: actually, maybe it's sufficient to keep track of the number of times an index is the start and the end of a range, and when printing the array, you can keep a running count of the number of increments at the current index

Comment: You just keep an array of deltas, initially all 0.
 `update(2,5) [0,1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0]`.
 `update(3,4) [0,1,1,0,-1,-1,0,0,0,0]`.
 `update(1,3) [1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0]`.
 `update(5,6) [1,1,1,-1,0,-1,-1,0,0,0]`.
 Each query takes O(1). Printing the final array takes O(n).

Comment: check out "segment tree lazy propagation"